# Jquery full calander control getting wrong date in drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have date upon which a external event was dropped.

I used whole code from this source.
http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/demos/external-dragging.html

And changed 'drop' event as following.

```
drop: function(date) {

  dataString = 'my_date=' + date;


    $.ajax({

        url: 'update-test.php',
        data: dataString ,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(returnData) { 
            alert(returnData);  // alerts wrong date
                    }
        });

    }
```

==================================================

update-test.php file has following code.   I am getting wrong date here.

HERE is PHP OPEN TAG(< ?php)

```
echo    $date = date('Y-m-d',$_POST['my_date'] );
```

Comment: Are there any errors? What is your HTML? What exactly is happening?

Comment: Please be more specific. Show your 'event_start_date', and the values you are getting / expecting.